# Facebook SDK 4.x Permission issue iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get **Feed** for logged in user's timeline. I have a login button, to which I am passing read permissions including `user_posts`. Amazingly, Facebook does not grant me this permission and ignores it.

**Code:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.loginButton.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends", @"user_posts"];

    self.loginButton.delegate = self;

    if([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken])
    {
        NSLog(@"Have access token");
        NSLog(@"permissions .... %@",[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].permissions);
        [self retrieveFeed];
    }

}

#pragma mark - Login Delegate

-(void) loginButton:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton didCompleteWithResult:(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Login Successfully!!");
    NSLog(@"permissions .... %@",[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].permissions);

    [self retrieveFeed];

}

-(void) loginButtonDidLogOut:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton
{

}

#pragma mark - Receive FB Feed

-(void) retrieveFeed
{       
    FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"/me/feed" parameters:nil];

    FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection = [[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection alloc] init];
    [connection addRequest:request completionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"%@",result);

        if(error)
            NSLog(@"Some error FEED;;;;;; %@",error.localizedDescription);
    }];
    [connection start];
}
```

On Clicking login Button, I get following permissions screen. Facebook has ignored `user_posts` permission.

[image]

Even if I try to get this permission later after login, Facebook tells me that *I have already authorized app to do so*, even when there is *no such* permission granted! The code for getting new permission is:

```
-(void) checkForFeedPermission
{
    if ([[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] hasGranted:@"user_posts"]) {

        NSLog(@"already granted feed access");
          [self retrieveFeed];

    } else {
        FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
        [loginManager logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"user_posts"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {

            NSLog(@"requesting feed access");
             [self retrieveFeed];

        }];
    }
}
```

I have been banging my head on this issue for three days. Please suggest me where can I be wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think that not working for grant `user_posts` as par [Facebook developer documentation for permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2) you have to submit your Facebook app for review see i attach screenshot that clearly said.

[image]

So you have to submit your [facebook app for login review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review#submitlogin) might be then you can able to set this permission at loginTime

Comment: So that means, I won't be able to get any permission without facebook review??

Comment: Yes. Permissions that require review are generally reviewed within 3 business days. Some permissions may take up to 7 days to review, and are marked as such in the reference. Permissions That Do Not Require Review: Public profile (default) permissions, App friends, Email permissions.

Comment: that is not for any permission that is for user_post

Comment: Better submit for review with the help of this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login

Answer (score 0):

If you are in development mode and not yet ready to publish the app for facebook review then the best way to do what you want is to use Test Users. In your facebook app dashboard go to Roles and create some test users. Note that its a separate tab and not Testers in the first tab. When you create test users you can by default assign what permissions should be assigned to that user.