# fbgraph api not returning data

Tags: ios, objective-c, fb-graph

I have a question regarding the graph api. I am using this link for getting the photos from my album. `https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?access_token=......`Here my issue is earlier it is returning the data but since last 3 to 4 days it is not returning the data . It is returning the empty data. I have checked all the apis of facebook but didn't find any documentation. Could any one please tell me what could be the issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried the Graph API Explorer?

Comment: Similar case like mine. See answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29820630/facebook-sdk-4-x-permission-issue-ios